# How to store time spent or total duration in Java?

Tags: java, time, apache-poi, duration

I am automating a excel report using the POI API for Java. I will have few reports in my disposal which I read using POI, process them, and create a new excel report.

One of columns from an excel file has total time spent, that is, it could in following format, `46:23:12` - this reads as `46 hours, 23 minutes and 12 seconds`.

I understand how to read date and time values and I usually store them in `java.util.Date`. The problem here is this is a time duration, the hours spent could be more than 24. Which datatype could be suitable for this? And how do I read this using POI?

Comment: What's your java version?

Comment: I can use any as needed.

Comment: I'm not sure what options POI provides but Excel stores times as fractions of a day (i.e. 0.5 would mean 12:00pm). Thus you could try to read that cell as a decimal number and then convert that to whatever representation you need (e.g. a `Duration`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java 8, an amount of time is represented by the [class `java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

I'm not sure if Apache POI has methods to deal directly with a `Duration`, so I believe that the best approach is to get the value as `String`, 
then parse this `String` to get the values and add those values to the `Duration`:

```
String s = "46:23:12";
String[] values = s.split(":");
// get the hours, minutes and seconds value and add it to the duration
Duration duration = Duration.ofHours(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
duration = duration.plusMinutes(Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
duration = duration.plusSeconds(Integer.parseInt(values[2]));
```

The `duration` object will contain the amount equivalent to the input (in this case: 46 hours, 23 minutes and 12 seconds). If you call `duration.toString()`, it returns this duration in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations):

> PT46H23M12S

---

Of course this code assumes that the input `String` always contains the three fields (hours, minutes and seconds). But you could check for `values.length` before parsing the values (and also call the  `plus` methods only if the respective value is not zero).

---

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

Comment: This answer is right. Added some extension here https://medium.com/@tareq021/add-time-duration-4ae6bd1d60c0

Answer (score 1):

There is a **Period** class which you can use in **Java 8**.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day );
LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate(year, month, day);

Period diff = Period.between(startDate , endDate);
```

Of course, I missed how this was about hours, minutes and seconds.

For this, there is **Duration**.

```
Duration timeDiff = Duration.ofMillis( startTime.getTime() , endTime.getTime() );
```

Comment: `Duration` would be better suited since `Period` needs a defined start and end date.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry for that, OP.

Answer (score 0):

Data types supported by Apache POI are listed [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html).

I would recommend using 0x15, "h:mm:ss" among all.

You can use the following two code blocks to read and write. But after reading you should manually parse the string.

To write total time spent into a new file:

```
final HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
final Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("SHEET ONE");

final CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat((short) 0x15);

final Row completeRow = sheet.createRow(0);
final Cell cell = completeRow.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("46:23:12");
cell.setCellStyle(style);

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/one.xls"));
workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

To read total time spent from existing file:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/tmp/one.xls");
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("SHEET ONE");

for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        final String stringCellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();

        System.out.println("stringCellValue = " + stringCellValue);
    }
}

fileInputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct and meets the requirements completely. This answer provides some additional details as well as an alternative way to create [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string from the given string of `46:23:12`.

[`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on ISO-8601 standards and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String iso8601DurationString = toIso8601DurationString("46:23:12");
        System.out.println(iso8601DurationString);

        Duration duration = Duration.parse(iso8601DurationString);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format(
                "%02d Day %02d Hour %02d Minute %02d Second %d Millisecond %d Nanosecond", duration.toDays(),
                duration.toHours() % 24, duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60,
                duration.toMillis() % 1000, duration.toNanos() % 1000000000L);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%02d Day %02d Hour %02d Minute %02d Second %d Millisecond %d Nanosecond",
                duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart(),
                duration.toMillisPart(), duration.toNanosPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################
    }

    static String toIso8601DurationString(String duration) {
        char[] symbols = "HMS".toCharArray();
        String[] durationParts = duration.split(":");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("PT");
        for (int i = 0; i < durationParts.length; i++) {
            sb.append(durationParts[i]).append(symbols[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT46H23M12S
PT46H23M12S
01 Day 22 Hour 23 Minute 12 Second 0 Millisecond 0 Nanosecond
01 Day 22 Hour 23 Minute 12 Second 0 Millisecond 0 Nanosecond
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).